# Google Cloud API (sheet, slides) Quotas with Service Account

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, google-sheets-api, access-token, google-slides-api

I wanna switch to a service account to remove access token duration.

However, I can't find the quotas here. Do quotas for Service Account are the same than user account and (actually 60) requests per user per minute ?

Answer (score 1):

Service accounts are under the same quota limitations as standard Oauth2.  A service account is still a user who is logging in so there for it will still be limited to the 60 requests per user per minute. Service accounts can actually have worse quota usage as sometimes it appears that a service account is the same user all the time even if it is preforming actions on behalf of different users. thats why you should remember to tell it which user to act as.

Using a service account will also not remove access token duration. It just gets a new access token when ever it needs the same as standard oauth2 does using a refresh token.

Comment: Thanks a lot Linda!
I didn't understand about duration. My regular user token expire 7 days and I have to manually run the app to log into google and have a new token. With service token, can it be automatic ?
I now the max user is 10 per project, is it also the case for service user ? Can I create 10 service accounts per project to increase my quotas from 60 to 600 req/user/min? I cant inscrease any quotas and google is not responding for prices of API quotas inscrease :/

------- "You cannot request more quotas because your project is not associated with a billing account."

Comment: Your tokens expire after 7 days if your app is in test once its in production refresh tokens won't expire. There is no max user Per project. Only use a service account if you are accessing your data you the developer control

Comment: Thanks. Google refused to put in prod, I have to stay in test mode. I needed users to expand quotas but I am the only one who use the app, I use sheets api as database. Does service token expires in 7 days too?

Comment: you can put it in production its just a button.  Nothing stops you from clicking on it.   I think you misunderstanding something.   Again dont use service accounts unless it is to access an account you the developer control. If you are connecting to user data you must use Oauth2 and request consent.